# Deploying a Java AWS Lambda function with container images

Tags: java, aws-lambda, docker-image

I currently have an AWS Lambda Function that I have deployed via a docker image. I created this docker image by doing the following

1.) Creating the following DockerFile:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi:8.1 as base

# install common tools
#RUN yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
RUN yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y sudo bash curl wget man-db nano bash-completion
RUN yum install -y java-11-openjdk-devel
RUN java -version

COPY OptimizerMarsExecutorFunction/build/classes/java/main ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
CMD ["optimizerMarsExecutor.OptimizerMarsExecutorFunction::handleRequest"]
```

2.) I then built the image then pushed it to AWS ECR (Elasic Container Registry)

3.) From there I navigated to AWS Lambda in the AWS console and created a custom Lambda Function via the Container Image option
[image]

4.) Following that in the "Edit image configuration" menu for the **ENTRYPOINT** value I added
`"OptimizerMarsExecutorFunction.class", "optimizerMarsExecutor.OptimizerMarsExecutorFunction::handleRequest"`

5.) I left the CMD and WORKDIR values empty.

6.) When I test my Lambda Function via the test option in AWS I receive the following error message

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 85bbd04d-621e-4268-a5a1-e78cf5536eae Error: exec: \"\\\"OptimizerMarsExecutorFunction.class\\\"\": executable file not found in $PATH"
}
```

I'm not certain what parameters I have to update and/or correct. I used the following as a reference point for how to go about this process: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-image.html#java-image-clients

Also, here is the folder structure of my project

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Isn't ENTRYPOINT supposed to be an executable plus arguments, e.g. `"/usr/bin/java", "-cp", "./*", "com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda"`?

Comment: AWS Lambda isn't a generic container runtime, it will only run containers that implement the Lambda Runtime API. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-reqs The docker image you are trying to use does not appear to implement that API.

Comment: @MarkB But you can create a docker image that contains a Lambda Function according to the following documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-image.html#java-image-clients. Also the purpose of the following line is to include the Lambda Function within the image:                                                                                                                                     COPY OptimizerMarsExecutorFunction/build/classes/java/main ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

Comment: @ruakh Your suggestion got me a little further. The error I recieve now is Error: Could not find or load main class com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda. I think this may be related to the Lambda not being copied to the Docker Image with the command COPY OptimizerMarsExecutorFunction/build/classes/java/main ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}. How can I ensure that the Lambda Function is being copied to the Docker Image?

Comment: @ruakh I made the change you suggested but now I get the following error.  
                                                                                                                             
Could not find or load main class com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda